# Fetch creating infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a couple problems with a fetch I'm making to my api in my react profile view. I'm not able to view the data in a p element of the render but I am able to view the user object my profile function spits out in the render... also the function loops forever, never displaying the data in the p element like I want but making unlimited fetchs and spitting out the correct object to the console. I feel like I'm doing a few things wrong here. Help please.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import { useAuth0 } from "../react-auth0-spa";

const Profile = () => {
  const { loading, user } = useAuth0();
  function subSplitter(subscriber){
    return subscriber.sub.split("|")[1];

  }

var sub = subSplitter(user);

console.log(sub);

  const [showResult, setShowResult] = useState(false);
  const [apiMessage, setApiMessage] = useState("");
  const { getTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const responseData = [];

const getGames = async () => {
  try {
    const token = await getTokenSilently();

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/users/" + sub, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });

    const responseData = await response.json();

    setShowResult(true);
    setApiMessage(responseData);
    console.log(responseData.games);
    return responseData.games;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
var stringUser = JSON.stringify(user, null, 2);
var gottenGames = JSON.stringify(responseData.Games, null, 2);
getGames();

  if (loading || !user) {
    return <Loading />;
  };

  return (

          <div>
            <img
              src={user.picture}
              alt="Profile"
              className="rounded-circle img-fluid profile-picture mb-3 mb-md-0"
            />

            <h2>{user.name}</h2>
            <p className="lead text-muted">{user.email}</p>

          <p>{stringUser}</p>
          <p>{gottenGames}</p>
          </div>

  );
  };

export default Profile;
```

Comment: `getGames` is async, you call `getGames()`, but don't wait for it to do anything, I guess somewhere in `getGames` the value of `loading` is set to false or `user` is given a value - but you don't wait for that

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is not the correct way to fetch data in **React**. The code snippet below shows how to do data fetching in React. There is something called the [useEffect] hooks that allows you to do side-effecting actions in a component.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import { useAuth0 } from "../react-auth0-spa";

const Profile = () => {
  const { loading, user } = useAuth0();
  function subSplitter(subscriber) {
    return subscriber.sub.split("|")[1];
  }

  var sub = subSplitter(user);

  console.log(sub);

  const [showResult, setShowResult] = useState(false);
  const [apiMessage, setApiMessage] = useState("");
  const { getTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const responseData = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    const getGames = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await getTokenSilently();

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/users/" + sub, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        });

        const responseData = await response.json();

        setShowResult(true);
        setApiMessage(responseData);
        console.log(responseData.games);
        return responseData.games;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    getGames();
  }, []);

  var stringUser = JSON.stringify(user, null, 2);
  var gottenGames = JSON.stringify(responseData.Games, null, 2);

  if (loading || !user) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src={user.picture}
        alt="Profile"
        className="rounded-circle img-fluid profile-picture mb-3 mb-md-0"
      />

      <h2>{user.name}</h2>
      <p className="lead text-muted">{user.email}</p>

      <p>{stringUser}</p>
      <p>{gottenGames}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

All I changed to your code was wrap your data fetching call inside an **useEffect** hook.

One more thing to note here is that doing this `const responseData = [];` is probably a bad idea. Mutations in React should only be handled using `useState` or the component state for class-based components. So your `reponseData` should actually look like this snippet below.

```js
// declaring state variable
const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState([]);

// inside your data fetching function
const data = await response.json();
setResponseData(() => data.games)
```

Let me know if this clears things up or not!

Comment: Not a problem. Do you mind accepting the answer, if you found it useful? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are aware of the **async** behavior of javascript. So I am noting down some bugs in your code:

1. So `var gottenGames = JSON.stringify(responseData.Games, null, 2);` is executing before you call **API** to assign data to it thus it got `undefined`;
2. Another problem is `const responseData = [];` you declare **const** to **responseData** in component and also in `getGames function` so returned data is only assign to local const variable inside the function and `outer const` variable did not change.

**One of the Solution:** `

gottenGames = getGames();` you directly assign returned data to **gottenGames** and initially declare it empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning the return value of `getGames()` to anything.

Try changing this ..

```
var gottenGames = JSON.stringify(responseData.Games, null, 2);
getGames();
```

To this ...

```
var gottenGames = JSON.stringify(getGames(), null, 2);
```